# Is there a way to use CMD + DELETE, and similar commands in Netbeans?

Tags: macos, netbeans

Normally, in Mac OSX Lion, you can delete words or even a whole line by holding `option` or `command` and pressing `delete`. However, you cannot do this in Netbeans IDE for some reason. Is there a way to enable all of Mac's modifier commands for Netbeans IDE?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `Option` and `Delete` delete a complete word for me (10.6, NetBeans 7). In fact, my NetBeans respects all common OS X shortcuts, only the Emacs bindings don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular one (CMD + DELETE deleting 1 character) always bugged me.  Finally got around to fixing it today:

- Preferences
- Keymap
- (Profile: Netbeans)
- Search: delete
- double-click the shortcut column for "Delete Preceding Characters in Line"
- press CMD+DELETE (it will show up as Meta+BACK_SPACE)
- OK

Haven't run into any others myself, glad to finally fix this one though.